# What database tables do I have to edit to get a product to show up in a Ubercart store?

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I am trying to create a ubercart module which automatically updates product listings.  I thought that I just needed to edit these tables

```
uc_products
uc_product_classes
uc_product_features
```

The problem is no matter what I put in these tables, no products are listed in the Ubercart store.

What other tables do I need to update to do this?  Or what steps do I need to take to get this module to add and/or update the products viewed in the web page?  I would love it if someone could show me how to do it without resorting to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are a lot more tables to alter before it will show in the Ubercart store.  However I don't think you need uc_product_features.

These tables are

```
node
node_type
node_revisions 
uc_products
uc_product_classes
```

They must belong to a class defined in uc_product_classes and node_type.

node_revisions is what is displayed in the store front and node.staus must be set to 1.  It is the publish variable.

Also

```
node.nid must equal mode_revision.nid
```

and

```
node_revsion.vid must equal mode.vid
```

otherwise in the store front listing for that item will be

```
"n/a"
```

And while it didn't tell me all I needed, I found the following site to be informative.

http://tiger-fish.com/blog/drupal-6-turning-existing-node-type-ubercart-product

Comment: Have received new info, and may find a better way of doing this than using SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6, products are referenced to nodes.  You might look at the feeds or node import module for automated product listing updates/creation.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where can I find feeds or node import module code?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/feeds                                      http://drupal.org/project/node_import                                 There are various tutorials out there on how to import/update content in Ubercart.  As with all things I'd recommend not re-inventing the wheel unless an existing solution can't meet your needs in less time.

Comment: Yes well I have been kinda thrown into the deep end.  Thanks will have a look at these two modules

Comment: I do get the feeling that these solutions won't meet my specific needs though